# How to set a toggle button based on what is in my ViewModel

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a viewModel, and in my activity_main.xml file I have a simple toggle button that turns something on or off.  In the onclick of that toggle button I set the on/off value in my viewModel.  I just want to have the state of that toggle button tied to that variable inside the viewModel.  For example if another fragment or piece of code updates the value in the viewModel I want it tied to this on/off toggle button too.

I see things about binding or maybe something like this in the xml file         `android:checked="@{userModel.unitsChecked}"`  but I don't see how it knows how to get an instance of my view model (called userModel).

What's the right way to do this in Android land?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ViewBinding is a auto-generated class that solves the problem of using FindViewById() throughout your codebase. It also provides Two-way binding if needed. To enable view binding, enable it in your project like below:

```
// Available in Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0
android {
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

For Android studio Canary Version:

```
// Android Studio 4.0
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Then, when you will build the app, each layout will have a binding file auto generated. If your layout file has the name `Activity_main.xml`, then `MainActivityBinding` file gets generated which you can use in your viewModel.

Now, you can use this binding class inside your viewModel to get your views and set their properties:

```
// Using view binding in an Activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    binding.title.text = "Hello"
    binding.subtext.text = "Concise, safe code"
    binding.button.setOnClickListener { /* ... */ }

    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Comment: for your last sentence, rather than viewModel, did you mean to say "...inside your Activity..."?

Answer (score 0):

In your userModel, declare unitsChecked as a LiveData
Then in your xml, set unitsChecked as follows:
android:checked="@{userModel.unitsChecked}
Then update your LiveData with unitsChecked.value = true